# Author tag checkstyle warning when using Intellij Inspect Code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc, checkstyle, code-inspection

When I use IntelliJ's *Inspect Code*, the IDE shows the following warning message:

```
Name      
    Test.java
Location
    package test.exercisefile Test.java
Problem synopsis
    Checkstyle: @author=John.Doe (at line 32)
```

My actual source comment is:

```
/**
 * @author John.Doe
 **/
public class Test {...
```

I have no idea what `@author=John.Doe` means.
I appreciate any advice about how to fix this warning. Thanks!

Comment: By the way I am using Intellij CheckStyle-IDEA and imported a customzed checkstyle xml file.  
The author tag's definition is
`<module name="WriteTag">
    <property name="tag" value="@author"/>
    <property name="tagFormat" value="\S"/>
    <property name="tagSeverity" value="ignore"/>
 </module>`

Comment: I think I have figured it out.
But I don't know why tag will also be outputed when the tagSeverity is ignore.

actually the author checkstyle's format is
<module name="JavadocType">
   <property name="authorFormat" value="\S"/>
</module>

use this than WriteTag will solve this issue.